Perform multiple lines in atomic way in compute shader
I am implementing a marching cubes algorithm in Unity using a compute shader. In my current implementation all the necessary data is stored in RWStructuredBuffer's with a theoretical maximum size. The key lines of code which appends vertices and normals to the corresponding buffers are:
RWStructuredBuffer<int> verticesCounter;
RWStructuredBuffer<float3> vertices;
RWStructuredBuffer<int> verticesIndices;
RWStructuredBuffer<float3> normals;

[numthreads(8, 8, 8)]
void listTrianglesAndGenerateVertices(int3 cellCorner : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    float3 vertex = ...
    float3 normal = ...
    int index = 0;
    InterlockedAdd(verticesCounter[0], 1, index);
    vertices[index] = vertexGlobal;
    normals[index] = normal;
    verticesIndices[...] = index;
}

I need to keep track of the index of each vertex in the vertices buffer as I have a subsequent kernel which retrieves the three vertex indices for each triangle in the mesh. This works, but I want to replace the vertices and normals buffers with AppendStructuredBuffer's to save on memory requirements. Ideally, I could do something like this:
RWStructuredBuffer<int> verticesCounter;
AppendStructuredBuffer<float3> vertices;
RWStructuredBuffer<int> verticesIndices;
AppendStructuredBuffer<float3> normals;

[numthreads(8, 8, 8)]
void listTrianglesAndGenerateVertices(int3 cellCorner : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    float3 vertex = ...
    float3 normal = ...
    int index = 0;
    // Following lines must occur in an atomic way
    InterlockedAdd(verticesCounter[0], 1, index);
    vertices.Append(vertex);
    normals.Append(normal);
    // End atomic lines
    verticesIndices[...] = index;
}

To ensure that the index is correct I can't have any race conditions between InterlockedAdd() and vertices.Append() and normals.Append(). Is the a way to do this? If not, is there some other way to safely get the index of the vertex in the vertices buffer?
